# Jest/Enzyme Shallow mixes child component names and stubbed components

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

Currently using Jest and Enzyme to select some elements for for my top level component. Using snapshot testing I am able to see what Enzyme shallow renders for me to select elements. How ever I did notice that in the snapshot, some elements get rendered with their component name and others gets replaced with `Component`

My top level component (**Note I stripped and modified some code to explain my point**):

```
import React from 'react'
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react'

import styles from './awesome.styl'

import { Input } from '../ilovepie/Input'
import { Button } from '../ilovepie/Button'
import { Title } from '../ilovepie/Title'
import { Subtitle } from '../ilovepie/Subtitle'


import { labels } from './labels'

@observer
export default class Awesome extends React.Component<> {

  // Some methods

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.Awesome}>
        <Title>{labels.title}</Title>
        <div className={styles.subTitle}>
          <Subtitle size={2} weight={1} color="light">
            {labels.subtitle}
          </Subtitle>
        </div>

        <Input
          testId={'email'}
          onChange={(email) => {}}
          error={this.isEmailValid ? null : labels.invalidEmail}
          label={labels.email}
          value={this.email}
        />

        <Input
          testId={'password'}
          onChange={(password) => {}}
          label={labels.password}
          value={this.password}
          isPassword
        />

        <div className={styles.actions}>
          <Button
            testId={'login'}
            onClick={() => {}}
            text={labels.signIn}
            isDisabled={this.loginDisabled}
            isLoading={this.isLoading}
          />
          <Button onClick={this.register} isSecondary isDoubleLines>
            {labels.notMember}
            <br />
            {labels.createAccount}
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And a Simple Test

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme'

let wrapper: ShallowWrapper

import Awesome from '.'

describe('<Awesome />', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // Somewhere down the road, how we are exporting React Components is exporting
    // it in a wrapper. Hence we need the `.dive()` to see the actual component
    wrapper = shallow(<Awesome />).dive()

  })

  describe("<Awesome /> 's rendering", () => {
    it('should match HTML Snapshot', () => {
      expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
  })
)}
```

Running this with the Snapshot returned:

```js
// Jest Snapshot v1,

exports[`<Awesome /> <Awesome /> 's rendering should match HTML Snapshot 1`] = `
<div
  className="Awesome"
>
  <Component>
    Hi There!
  </Component>
  <div
    className="subTitle"
  >
    <Component
      color="light"
      size={2}
      weight={1}
    >
      It's a awesome day.
    </Component>
  </div>
  <Input
    error={null}
    label="Email Address"
    onChange={[Function]}
    testId="email"
    value=""
  />
  <Input
    isPassword={true}
    label="Password"
    onChange={[Function]}
    testId="password"
    value=""
  />
  <div
    className="actions"
  >
    <Component
      isDisabled={true}
      isLoading={false}
      onClick={[Function]}
      testId="login"
      text="SIGN IN"
    />
    <Component
      isDoubleLines={true}
      isSecondary={true}
      onClick={[Function]}
    >
      Not a member yet?
      <br />
      Create an account!
    </Component>
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

Why are some components renamed to `</Component>` and some kept it's original name like `<Input ... />`? Is it because the component names are closely related to HTML elements? If so why is `Button` replaced?

I would love to know if there is an GH issue or if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/name.html), names are calculated as follows
`type.displayName` -> `type.name` -> `type`

Your snapshot falls back to `Component` as a type since theres no name for your custom components.

One way to solve this is to give your components a static `displayName` property.

```
class Title extends Component {
  static displayName = 'Title';
  ...
}
```